# UIScrollView zoomToRect vs setZoom

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

If I have a UIScrollView, and I want to zoom in on a location, is there any difference between just setting the zoom on scrollview like

```
self.scrollView.zoomScale = MY_NEW_ZOOM;
```

versus calculating a new rectangle within the zoom to zoom in on, and using

```
zoomToRect:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `zoomScale` just sets the zoom scale and doesn't change the content offset.
2. `zoomToRect:` will change the zoom scale *and* the content offset such that the rect you have given will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, you may want to ensure that the size of the rect you pass in zoomToRect: is the size of the scrollview's frame. Otherwise the Zoom and Content Offset might not end up where you expect it.